# How to terminate bound ForegroundService after reboot

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-service

I have bounded ForegroundService, when last client unbinds ForegroundService is destroyed and it is what I want.
In case when client is bounded with service and I restart device, after reboot Android OS restarting previously started service. When client binds again to service I have two notifications so two Foreground Services are runnng. How I can stop service which has been launched before reboot ?

It is possible to find currently running Foreground Service and stop him before starting new one ?

Comment: why don't you START_NOT_STICKY your service instead of START_STICKY which will makes the system not creating the service before rebooting

Comment: @RamyIbrahim I tried with startService() and boundService() and with START_NOT_STICKY but service is still running after reboot